# ng test Command Fails on Azure Pipeline

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I removed node_modules and package_lock.json using Azure pipeline. but still i am facing the following Error.

The Error " error ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\DevOps-AgentPools-sr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\tmp'" showing continuously

[image]

Comment: What does the pipeline configuration look like?